# Как добавить миниатюры к slick слайдеру?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Как добавить миниатюры к slick слайдеру(маленькие картинки слайдов, как правило, снизу слайдера, при клике на которые слайдер переключается на соответствующую картинку, как здесь: http://fotorama.io/ )? Что добавить к коду?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.main-slider').slick({
              lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              autoplay: true,
              autoplaySpeed: 8000,
              infinite: true, 
              dots: false,
              speed: 800,
              fade: true,
              pauseOnHover: false
          });
        });
```

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под "миниатюрами"?

Comment: маленькие картинки слайдов, как правило, снизу слайдера, при клике на которые слайдер переключается на соответствующую картинку.

Comment: Это dots - измените false на true и с помощью css кастомизируйте точки так, чтобы они стали миниатюрами (увеличьте размер, вставьте в качестве фона соответствующие картинки и т.д.). Исходные стили dots - в slick-theme.css, меняйте их по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Спасибо. Я, правда, надеялся, что это полегче делается, но тем не менее.))

Answer (score 1):

У slick slider есть свойство custom paging, напишите data-image в каждый слайд и соберите кастомные булеты (в вашем случае картинки)

```js
$(".slider").slick({
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
        var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('image');
        return '<a href="#"><img src="'+thumb+'"></a>';
    },

   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант связать 2 слайдера:

```js
$('.slider-win').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-controll',
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  
});

$('.slider-controll').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  vertical: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-win',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: false,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150xp;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide.slick-current {
  border-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-win">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
</div>
  
<div class="slider-controll">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
</div>
```

Или вариант с обычной навигацией по слайдам:

```js
var $Slider = $('.slider-win').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',

});

$('.slider-item').on('click', function(e) {

  var slideIndex = $(this).data('item');
  
  $(this).addClass('on').siblings().removeClass('on');

  $Slider.slick( 'slickGoTo', parseInt( slideIndex ) - 1 );

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slider-controll {
  display: flex;
}

.slider-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150xp;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}

.slider-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}

.slider-item.on {
  border-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-win">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
</div>
  
<div class="slider-controll">
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="3"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно еще 1 слайдер синхронизировать сделать вот в официальной документации написано http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ Slider Syncing называется. Почитайте очень все понятно написано и просто, как мне кажется проще некуда.

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```